# Different Response-Headers from API in Angular when using PC or iPad

Tags: angular, http-headers, angular-httpclient

In an Angular frontend app (in VS Code on Windows 11) I want to evaluate all headers that an API call returns, i.e. to save the session-id and JWT token. This works, but unfortunately only partially: only a handful of headers are returned, but not the important ones I need.

- It happens with Edge, Chrome, Firefox.
- In the browser developer mode under Network tab I see that all headers arrive completely (!). But not in the app.
- When I call the API with Postman, I can see all header in the response
- curl -I http://... returns all headers, same as Postman
- For testing purposes I disabled defender firewall completely - no change

**Most important, look at this page I found today:** [stackblitz demo page](https://stackblitz.com/edit/read-response-headers-in-angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) It demonstrates exactly what I want and **I can reproduce the problem there too**. Only four (from eleven) headers are displayed in the console on the right side. So that there are no misunderstandings: I call up the code directly on the stackblitz website, I have not copied it to my VS Code environment. And yet the same error appears. **The trick: when I call up the same page on my iPad, all eleven headers are displayed as they should. Crazy.**

- ipad and PC are in the same network.
- The problem also occurs on another Windows 10 PC on the same network.
- Update 12/3/23: I tried Ubuntu as a VitualBox VM Boot on my PC, same error, only 4 of 11 Headers were displayed.

I'm totally confused. Why does it work on iPad and not on PC? Is it related to processor architecture? Weird.

I tried to add stackblitz screenshots from ipad (ok) and PC (not ok) to demonstrate the different behaviour. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to include screenshots, even if they are links.